# Custom Email Confirmation Page in Experience Cloud

Tags: community, email, security, experience-cloud, confirmation

I have a problem, when *Customer Community Login* user change their email, old and new emails with address confirmation are sent by SF and standard page with button opens.
[image: Custom email confirmation page]

Is there any way to replace this page to the custom one or at least change redirection from **/home/home.jsp** to some other page?
We are not interested in redirecting Community Users to Platform user entry point.

Comment: Change the [email template](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.networks_email_change_template.htm&type=5) and in your new template provide a link to your own custom page(s)

Comment: @identigral Hello,
Thank you for your answer. As for now, I use custom email template and as article suggest, use "{!ChgEmailVer.URL}" to get confirmation link.
If I replace this merge field with link to my customer VF page, I think that will not work, because this merge field generate special link, for example 
"https://aaaaaaaa.my.salesforce.com/setup/emailverif?oid=00D3Z&k=Cj4KNQoPMDBEM00". I don't know how to generate something like that for my VF page.
Thank you for your answer.

Comment: You're reimplementing the entire sequence, thus you have to generate your own link, don't use `ChgEmailVer.URL`

Comment: @identigral
Hello, could you please provide an example?

Comment: @identigral
Basically, I have found a similar question [https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/275667/custom-email-confirmation-process-in-salesforce/276185], but I don't know what fields on User record control this 'pending' status for the email. So my target is to set this 'pending' status to 'Active' lest's say. Could you please give me the name of this field, because I can't found.
Many thanks.

Comment: [`TwoFactorMethodsInfo.HasUserVerifiedEmailAddress`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_twofactormethodsinfo.htm) is what you're after but you can't modify this object via Apex DML. You'll need to call one of the System.UserManagement methods or keep track of verification status in your own, custom field.

Comment: @identigral
Thank you for the link. Now it's more clear for me.
I have checked System.UserManagement method, but unfortunately I didn't find any method which can help me. 
Correct me if I'm wrong:
1. I would like to use VF email with $Network.ChgEmailVerOldEmail merge fields, but it doesn't work (empty values).
2. Instead of {ChgEmailVer.URL} I will use a link to my custom VF page with unique param.
3. When user click the link, I will take this param from URL and check if param is still valid (some validation by my own) and update email status.
So, which UserManag. Method should I use?

Comment: [`initPasswordlessLogin/verifyPasswordlessLogin`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_System_UserManagement.htm#apex_System_UserManagement_initPasswordlessLogin)